# How to insert 100 MB without making a 100 MB insert statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a varbinary(max) column. I need this table to contain a large file. The file content doesn't matter. It can be zeroes or random. Is the only way to do that by sending a 100 MB insert statement? Is there any small script which could insert a value of that size?

Comment: You want small script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable
  (
     YourFileColumn VARBINARY(MAX)
  )

INSERT INTO #YourTable
            (YourFileColumn)
VALUES      ( CAST(REPLICATE(CAST(0XFF AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 
                             100 * 1024 * 1024) AS VARBINARY(MAX)))

SELECT DATALENGTH(YourFileColumn) /*104857600*/
FROM #YourTable

DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

Comment: This statement makes my log to overflow: "The transaction log for database 'DBK' is full"

Comment: @JaderDias If you are getting this error for a single row insert increase the size of the log then. If you are doing this for multiple rows you can either reduce the number of rows or increase the log size.